# How to dynamically reflect changes to a Razor Page Model on pages and database?

Tags: visual-studio, sqlite, asp.net-core, model, razor-pages

I'm building my first Razor Pages app by following [Microsoft's tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/razor-pages/razor-pages-start?view=aspnetcore-3.0&tabs=visual-studio), and I'm curious about the correct way to reflect changes to my model on CRUD/scaffolded pages and corresponding database table. I have used below steps to handle this, but my solution feels more like a hack. Is there a better way to do it? I'm looking for a dynamic solution which allows for better separation of concerns.

**What I aim to do:** I want to remove `CVRnr` from below model, have the corresponding column in the database table dropped, as well as removing references to `CVRnr` on pages. The problem is that my changes to the model isn't reflected dynamically elsewhere in the project.

```
namespace Virksomhedsgodkendelser.Models
{
    public class Company
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }

        public int Pnr { get; set; }

        public int CVRnr { get; set; }
    }
}
```

**What I have done to solve this**:

1. Deleted `public int CVRnr { get; set; }` from the model
2. Deleted the CRUD pages in ~/Pages/Companies/
3. Re-added the CRUD pages via: Add > New Scaffolded Item > Razor Pages using Entity Framework
4. Deleted dbo.Company from my database
5. Re-added the database table via Package Manager Console: `Add-Migration InitialCreate` + `Update-Database`